# Light file copy with diff

Tags: files, cp, diff, overlayfs

Is there a way to copy a file by creating another instance of it, that is not created as a hard copy, but by a link with the difference that any edit to that file will be saved in an diff file?

I have in mind [OverlayFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) on a per-file-base